# Money transferred from France to the U.S

Tags: banking

My husband is French but now lives in the U.S. He just sold an apartment in Lyon, but wants to send the money to the U.S. Is there a limit to how much can be sent over. Is there a bank we could use to pay bills in the U.S. How does this work?

Comment: There is no limit.  Large companies make trillions worth of transactions all the time.

Comment: I presume the money is now in a bank account in Lyon.  The simplest solution is to have that bank wire the money to a US account.  That may not be the most cost-effective solution, however, as you might be able to find a better exchange rate elsewhere.